# Fetch request always returns network error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, request, fetch

I almost finished creating React Native application, few days ago register action has stopped working.. I'm sending fetch request and it always returns network error altough there is 400 response and message that user exists, it stops there..

I'm destructuring the response and displays api response message instead of fetch network error but now it doesn't work. I'm doing the same for the login action and it works.

Could it be something with multipart/form-data ?

```
export const register = data => dispatch => {
    dispatch(createUser());
    const d = new FormData();
    d.append("name", data.name);
    d.append("email", data.email);
    d.append("password", data.password);
    d.append("avatar", data.avatar);
    fetch(API_URL + "/register", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body:d
    })
    .then(response => response.json().then(user => ({ user, response })))
    .then(({ user, response }) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(response, user)
        } else {
            console.log(response, user)
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err;
    });
};
```

The api route works in Postman..

Comment: Is there more info in the console? Maybe it's a CORS error (Postman doesn't require CORS so it'd work there)?

Comment: Added `mode` to fetch request but nothing, I have `app.use(cors())` on my backend..

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your using fetch which is Promise based incorrectly,

Try,

```
fetch(API_URL + "/register", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
    body:d
})
.then(response => {
      console.log(response, response.json().user)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
});
```

Check the logs and see if it shows proper network response and debug from there.